# reference request for essential equivalence of top. groupoids

Tags: reference-request, groupoids, at.algebraic-topology

Let $G$ and $H$ be two *topological* groupoids. Recall that a morphism $F \colon H \to G$ is called an *essential equivalence*, if

- the map $t \circ \pi_1 \colon G_1 \times_{G_0} H_0 \to G_0$ is an open surjection, where $G_1 \times_{G_0} H_0$ is the pullback along the source map $s \colon G_1 \to G_0$.
- the following diagram is a pullback diagram:
  $$
  H_1 \to G_1 \\\\ 
  \downarrow \qquad  \downarrow \\\\
  H_0 \times H_0 \to G_0 \times G_0 
  $$
  where the vertical arrow are given by $(s,t)$.

Basically this means that $F$ is an equivalence of categories (where the first condition implies essential surjectivity and the second it fullness), but it need not necessarily have a continuous inverse. Nevertheless, such a map $F$ induces a weak homotopy equivalence $BF \colon BH \to BG$.

I think, I know how to prove this. But for a paper I would rather have a reference in the literature for this result. Unfortunately, this seems to be so well-known that nobody bothers to write down a proof.

> What is the best/first reference in the literature for the above statement?

Answer (score 4):

For example, this is proved as:

- Lemma 3.34 in Lerman, E.: [Orbifolds as stacks?](http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.4160)
- Proposition 60 in Metzler, D.S.: [Topological and Smooth Stacks](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.DG/0306176)

Comment: You should take Konrad's answer with a small grain of salt.   Lemma 3.34 can be said to prove that an essential equivalence between Lie groupoids H and G defines an isomorphism of corresponding stacks. I presume the same proof works for topological groupoids.  Then the result you want follows from a fact, the reference to which I don't know, that isomorphic stacks have homotopy equivalent classifying spaces (assuming that by $BG$ you mean the classifying space of a stack rather than the stack itself; the notation is ambiguous).



Comment: (continued) A good place to look for info on topological stacks are papers of Behrang Noohi (http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~noohi/)

Comment: I would use an argument like this: From your proof, I can deduce that principal $G$-bundles over $S^n$ are in $1:1$-correspondence (induced by the functor) with principal $H$-bundles. From this we obtain a weak equivalence between $BG$ and $BH$ induced by $F$.